# .htaccess redirect empty directories to index.php but it's showing function name instead of executing it

Tags: nginx, .htaccess

Hi I have a LEMP Server and I have used .htaccess file as bellow to redirect empty directories to index.php but the problem is that it's not executing the code in the index.php it's just printing the Array()

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

nginx server configuration

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /storage/html/stream;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name stream.example.com;
        include snippets/phpmyadmin.conf;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404 /rest/index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

}
```

phpMyAdmin location that I have included it in my server block

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    root /storage/html/stream/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        root /storage/html/stream/;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(doc|sql|setup)/ {
           deny all;
    }

    location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
        root /storage/html/stream/;
    }
}
```

And this is my index.php file

```
<?php

print_r($_GET);

require_once("app/config.php");

require_once("app/core/core.php");

require_once( "app/core/router.php");
```

This is the output for http://stream.example.com/rest/?path=video/server

```
Array
(
    [path] => video/server
)
{"authorization":0,"error":1,"result":0,"message":"Token is invalid."}
```

And this is the output for http://stream.example.com/rest/video/server

```
Array ( )
```

but they both should give me this output:

```
Array ( [path] => video/server/ )
```

can anyone help me with this problem ?

Comment: `.htaccess` is an Apache configuration file and you appear to be using Nginx.

Comment: "the problem is that it's not executing the code in the index.php it's just printing the Array()" - It IS executing the code in `index.php`, otherwise it wouldn't "print Array()". You just aren't passing the expected information to your script. `$args` is empty. `path=$uri` is "closer" to the sort of thing you are expecting. `'=404` in the `try_files` directive would seem to be redundant (and in the wrong order).

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have transfered the `index.php` file to root of the server and fixed this issue by adding `index.php?$uri` to my `try_files` and YeaP the .htaccess file wasn't working at all

But I have a question that if I want to have my `index.php` in a subdirectory what should I do ?

By the way the name of this type of configuration is ***Front Controller*** and you can search about it by this name

Thanks

Comment: "have my `index.php` in a subdirectory" - there shouldn't be a problem with that; what problem are you having?